# XMLHttpRequest eval

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, eval

It's working in IE. Need help for Firefox.

html code:

```
<img name="zastgo" src="../courseimages/button_wait.gif" width="166" height="31" border="0" onClick="comOn(); return false;">
```

js file:

```
preButton = new Image(166,31);
preButton.src = "../courseimages/button_start1.gif";

function waitForUser() {
if(system.ie == true) {
if (document.getElementById('zastgo')) {
    document.getElementById('zastgo').src = eval("preButton.src");
} 
} else {
    if(document.getElementsByName('zastgo')) {
        document.getElementsByName('zastgo').src = preButton.src;
    }
}
```

fixed. document.getElementsByName('zastgo')[0].src

Comment: cant load prebutton.src (gif)

Comment: you got any error at console?

Comment: why would you use eval in this situation!? you could aswell write `preButton.src`. I don't understand your use case

Comment: no errors. it just don't load with eval and without it.

Comment: paste your html also. and `src` path is correct?

Comment: edited, path is correct.